# Send data-attributes to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the following code in an attempt to send row data from the page to a modal window:

```
 <?php
   $select = "SELECT * FROM table";
   $res = mysql_query($select) or die();
     echo "<div>"
     echo "<table>"
     echo "<tr><th>Edit/Delete</th>
               <th>Group</th>
               <th>Type</th>
               <th>Service</th>
               <th>Description</th>
           </tr>";
     while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== FALSE){
       echo "<tr><td>
       <a href='' class='open-EditRow btn btn-primary' value='Edit'
         data-des=\"{$Row[description]}\" 
         data-group=\"{$Row[resgroup]}\" 
         data-type=\"{$Row[restype]}\" 
         data-service=\"{$Row[service]}\">Edit</a>
       </td>";
       echo "<td>{$Row[resgroup]}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$Row[restype]}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$Row[service]}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$Row[description]}</td></tr>\n";
       };
     echo "</table>";
     echo "</div>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0){
      echo "No Results";
    }
   }
 ?>
```

As you can see in the a tag above, I am using the data-attributes to get the row data, which includes resgroup, restype, service, and description.  At this point, I can get the modal window to open with no problem.

The javascript I am using looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function()
   {
     $('.open-EditRow').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $group = $(this).attr('data-group');
     $type = $(this).attr('data-type');
     $service = $(this).attr('data-service');
     $descript = $(this).attr('data-description');
     console.log($group);
     console.log($type);
     console.log($service);
     console.log($descript);
    });
   });
 </script>
```

I can do an alert($group) and the row data for data-group does indeed appear in the alert window.

My modal window has a form with input tags that I am trying to populate with the data-attributes.  The input tags have the a class, name, and id with the same name as the data-attributes themselves.

I know I do not need to use console.log(); but I am not sure how to pass the data any further than an alert window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are already using jQuery, so if the form inputs have ids that match the data-attribute names, I believe you should be able to fill them in [using the `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
$('#group').val($group);
```

You may also [use the `data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) to retrieve the data attributes. Instead of

```
$group = $(this).attr('data-group');
```

you can use

```
$group = $(this).data('group');
```

Comment: In my javascript, where would I apply $('#group').val($group); ?